# Sending input to prompt over SSH

Tags: ruby, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a server using `Net::SSH` with admin credentials. Immediately after login it executes a script that requires input of 'Yes' or 'No' and, based on the input, executes the next command.

Although I am able to connect, after sending `"Yes\n"` to the server the loop doesn't end. Why?

```
require 'net/ssh'
Net::SSH.start(Host, 'root',:port => "26", :password => "pass") do |ssh|
  ssh.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.request_pty(:term => "xterm") do |ch, success|
      if success
        puts "pty successfully obtained"
        ch.send_channel_request "shell" do |ch, success|
          if success                                          
            ch.send_data("su admin\n")                   
            ch.send_data("command\n")           
            ch.on_process do |data|         
              ch.send_data("yes\n")
              ch.send_data("command\n")
            end         
          else
            puts "could not start user shell"
          end
        end
      else
        puts "could not obtain pty"
      end
    end
  end
  ssh.loop
end
```

Comment: Can specify where in your code it is getting stuck?

Comment: After calling the send_data with the command and calling on_process for the prompt input for that command  loop doesn't end it is printing the same yes command. This is where we stuck up           ch.send_data("command\n")           
            ch.on_process do |data|         
              ch.send_data("yes\n")
              ch.send_data("command\n")         
            end